# How to Create id for Mapping with plotly.express

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, json-normalize

I have a dataframe "states" that has each states's child poverty rate and json file called "us_states".  I want to create a choropleth map using plotly express but I'm struggling to create the id column.  Here is my entire code.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import plotly.express as px

states = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ngpsu22/Child-Poverty-State-Map/master/poverty_rate_map.csv')

us_states = pd.read_json('https://github.com/ngpsu22/Child-Poverty-State-Map/raw/master/gz_2010_us_040_00_500k.json')

state_id_map = {}
for feature in us_states['features']:
  feature['id'] = feature['properties']['NAME']
  state_id_map[feature['properties']['STATE']] = feature['id']

states['id'] = states['state'].apply(lambda x: state_id_map[x])
```

But I get this error:
KeyError: 'Maine'
Which since Maine is first in my data frame means that something is going wrong.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `us_states.features` is a `dict`
- Use `pd.json_normalize` to extract the `dict` into a dataframe.
- `'geometry.coordinates'` for each row is a large nested list
- It's not clear what the loop is supposed to do, the data from the two dataframes can be joined together for easier access, using `pd.merge`.

```py
us_states = pd.read_json('https://github.com/ngpsu22/Child-Poverty-State-Map/raw/master/gz_2010_us_040_00_500k.json')

# convert the dict to dataframe
us_states_features = pd.json_normalize(us_states.features, sep='_')

# the Name column is addressed with
us_states_features['properties_Name']

# join the two dataframe into one
df = pd.merge(states, us_states_features, left_on='state', right_on='properties_NAME')
```

Comment: Yeah I think I understand but I'm getting new errors.  I thought plotly would make this simpler.  TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: @NateGo Open a new question for that with the updated code and the entire Traceback as text. comment here when you've got it and i'll look